# Get EClass from EMF model instance class

Tags: java, emf

Given any `Class<?> clazz` object, is there an API to get the `EClass` whose model instances implement `clazz`? (i.e. the `eClass` for which `eClass.getInstanceClass().equals(clazz)` is true)

If I had an `eObject`, I could simply call `eObject.eClass()` to get the `EClass`. But in my case I have no such instance. I only have a model instance class and need the associated `EClass` to call `EcoreUtil.create(eClass)`.

Comment: Can you give an example where you have to use this? Do you get `clazz` from a `obj.getClass()` where `obj` is an `EObject` instance or do you get `clazz` using a `InterfaceName.class` in your code (e.g: in UML, `Activity.class`)?

Comment: @VincentAranega I use `InterfaceName.class` because I don't have any `obj` at that point. It want to provide the method `create(InterfaceName.class)` as a alternative to `create(eClass)` because it can be typesafe and, as far as I know, to get an EClass I would need to either get it by name (`ePackage.getEClassifier("MyClass")`) or I would need to use strange references to `MyPackage.Literals.MY_CLASS` which I would like to avoid

Comment: Ok ok. I think I have a solution for you then :) (I'm writing this down).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to illustrate the answer, I will asume that we have a metamodel called `Foo` as in your previous answer and that the associated package is `FooPackage` and the associated factory is `FooFactory`. In this metamodel I will suppose we have `A` and `B` which are `EClass`.

In order to get the associated `EClass` to a `A.class`, you can use this:

```
String aName = A.class.getSimpleName();
EClassifier classif = FooPackage.eInstance.getEClassifier(aName);
if (classif != null && classif instanceof EClass) {
  // At this point, you have the right EClass, 
  // you can now create an instance using the factory
  EObject myinstance = FooFactory.eInstance.create((EClass)classif);
}
```

After that, you will need to deal with dynamic instances (your EObject) unless you explicitally cast`myinstance` into an `A` using this:

```
A instance = (A) myinstance;
// or 
A instance = A.class.cast(myinstance);
```

If you put all of this in a method, it could look like this:

```
public static <T> T create(java.lang.Class<T> clazz) {
  String iName = clazz.getSimpleName();
  EClassif classif = FooPackage.eInstance.getEClassifier(iName);
  if (classif != null && classif instanceof EClass) {
    return clazz.cast(FooFactory.eInstance.create((EClass)classif));
  }
  return null; // or throw exception, clazz not found or stuff like that
}
```

Please note that at this point, you have to be sure that the interface you will try to create (`A.class`) is indeed `EClass` and is not abstract, otherwise an exception will be raised.

In order to handle this kind of stuffs, I began to code a kind of library for this few month ago: https://github.com/aranega/dynemf

It is not yet fully documented, but you can do stuffs like this:

```
EPackageWrapper mymm = ePackage(FooPackage.eINSTANCE);
mymm.create(A.class)
  .set("name", "MyAInstance")
  .set("bRels", mymm.create(B.class)
                  .set("name", "MyB1"));
```

You can browse the code, perhaps it could help you.

Hope I understood right your issue.

Comment: Thanks! It relies on the model name being identical to the instance type name though, right? But it should work in most cases and probably will work for me.

Comment: Yes, it relies on the fact that the generated Interface name is exactly the same as the one you modeled in your `.ecore`. The `.getEClassifier(name)` on an `EPackage` is part of the EMF API and is usually used to deal with dynamic instances (without the need to generate the Java code from your `.ecore`). However, these "dynamic-reflexive" methods are slower than their generated counterparts.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any API for this. The relation between `EClass` and its instance class are set up by generated initializer methods but there isn't any reverse mapping. The reason for this seems to be be that there is no one-to-one relationship, because multiple model elements can use the same instance interface.

It's possible to iterate all `EClassifiers` and build a mapping yourself though, if you are sure that each class uses a distinct interface.

```
Map<Class<?>, EClass> eClasses = new HashMap<>();
for (final EClassifier eClassifier : FooPackage.eINSTANCE.getEClassifiers()) {
    if (eClassifier instanceof EClass) {
        if(eClasses.put(eClassifier.getInstanceClass(), (EClass) eClassifier) != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                 "Failed to create distinct instance class to EClass mapping for "
                 + Classifier.getInstanceClass());
        }
    }
}
```